# Is there a Visual Studio Extension which makes intellisense suck less?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

Ok in short I want to make the intellisense show me ALL possible parameters in a popup not just 1 of them and I have to spin up and down like crazy (how microsoft didnt fix that in the last 10 years ?)

I know resharper have it but resharper is expensive and I want just that.

In short I want something that makes intellisense look like that(from resharper):
[image]

Instead of the current crap that looks like that :
[image]

Start spining baby you have 19 options KEEP HITTING UP AND HOPE U WONT MISS IT ! :D

I hope you get the idea in short : to make intellisense work like every 10 years old Java IDE, 10 years ago.

Comment: I love this question :D Unfortunately, Resharper is the only one I know. Which is sort of a joke in itself, in the Java world, you get the most powerful IDE completely for free, and in the C# world, you have to buy an expensive IDE, then buy an expensive addon to make that IDE even remotely usable.

Comment: Yeah, but you don't have to use Java so it's worth it ;)

Comment: "the most powerful IDE completely for free"... Surely you're not talking about Eclipse? I'd rather rub my face on a cheesegrater than use that. :)

Comment: I think he's talking about IDEA)

Comment: the most powerful Java IDE is IntelliJ community edition.. to make it clear... Eclipse is the most used Java ide because of historical reasons and because 5 years ago there was no intellij community edition and the rest Jdeveloper, jbuilder and net beans was sucking more then visual studio ... stil visual studio is a peace of shit if we speak about code editor... it is ok for the wizards the UI and etc but the code editor is the biggest joke ever. I cannot imagine why if I write in a method argument params whatever .. and I forgot the [] the stupid IDE show error... lol welcome to 90s

Comment: If IntelliSense shows you auto-completion info for Console.WriteLine() when you are typing code for the ArgumentNullException then you have much bigger problems that no add-in is going to fix.  Ranty questions loaded with hyperbole don't ever have useful answers.